# How to use last created forms values for new form?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have the follow models:

```
User
 has_many :armies

Army
 belongs_to :user
```

My controller with the added `current_user`:

```
class ArmiesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  def new
    @army = Army.new
  end

  def create
    @army = current_user.armies.new(params[:army])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @army.save
        format.html { redirect_to new_army_path, :notice => "New army added" }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I want to use my last created forms value for the new one. We'll use my `strength` field as an example:

```
<%= form_for @army do |f| %>
   <%= f.label :strength, "Army Strength" %>
   <%= f.text_field :amount %>
   <%= f.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

How can I save the value that the user input's in the `strength` field so it remains on the form after the last form is created?

**EDIT:**

```
  def new
    @army = Army.new(strength: session[:last_army_strength], 
                     type_id: session[:last_type])
  end

  def create
    @army = current_user.armies.new(params[:army])
    session[:last_army_strength] = params[:army][:strength]
    session[:last_type] = params[:army][:type_id]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @army.save
        format.html { redirect_to new_army_path, :notice => "New army added" }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
class ArmiesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  def new
    @army = Army.new(strength: session[:last_army_strength])
  end

  def create
    @army = current_user.armies.new(params[:army])
    session[:last_army_strength] = params[:army][:strength]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @army.save
        format.html { redirect_to new_army_path, :notice => "New army added" }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Is it OK to have more then one session? I did this to all the fields I needed.

Comment: There is only one session per user. You can store as many variables as you want in it. If you want, you can also store arrays, hashes in it, to keep things more organised.

Comment: When you say one session. I don't understand because if you take a look at my edit, it allows me to do two sessions or maybe that's really saying one session. I guess theirs a better way to write this?

Comment: Nope, that's one session. session is a Hash. You can add as many variables as you want to it.